# Is there a way to overlay frames in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

As the title states, is there a way to stop the canvas / SKScene from clearing the contents of the current frame, and just draw over the current frame? Now the contents of the scene/frame are cleared every update cycle, i would like to just draw over the previous frame.

I have worked with OpenFrameworks and other visual programming frameworks, and the way it worked there was; you draw stuff on the `update` call, on the next `update` call you set a background again to 'clear' the previous frame.

I have looked through the whole documentation of SpriteKit and couldn't find anything. I also tried to emulate the effect by pushing more nodes onto the scene, having them follow one step behind the 'new' nodes. This was, as i expected, way to heavy on CPU / RAM.

No code, i know, i'm sorry, but the stuff i use is pretty basic. Any one of you have any thoughts on this?

Hope to hear from you, thanks.

Comment: i dont think theres going to be a way to do this and I'm not sure why you'd like to draw on a previous frame?

Comment: Yeah it's not really that i want to draw on the previous frame, more that i just don't want the canvas / context to clear each update. I guess there is no way to do this with spritekit..

Comment: The latest version of Sprite Kit slows down its update cycle if nothing changes for a while, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by setting the `clearsContextBeforeDrawing` property on your `SKView` to `NO`.

[clearsContextBeforeDrawing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clearsContextBeforeDrawing) is a property of UIView, which SKView is a subclass of.

I wouldn't consider this to technically be Sprite Kit providing the behavior, but I believe it's what you're looking for.

Note: I didn't actually test this, so it's possibly that this won't actually work. It would theoretically work perfectly for UIKit.

Comment: I checked and it looks like you can't rely on this to not clear the contents.